# Circle on Google Maps for Android v2 is flickering when size changes by seekbar

Tags: android, google-maps, geometry, shapes

I am implementing a way to show a search radius on a Google Map (v2) in Android per this method:

```
// Method for drawing a circle around the user
private void drawMapSearchRadius(int radius) {
    if(mMap != null) {
        final LatLng userLatLng = getUserLatLng();
        if(mSearchCircle == null){
            CircleOptions circleOptions = new CircleOptions();
            circleOptions.fillColor(Color.parseColor("#447755ff"));
            circleOptions.strokeColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
            circleOptions.center(userLatLng);
            circleOptions.radius(radius);
            mSearchCircle = mMap.addCircle(circleOptions);
        } else {
            mSearchCircle.setCenter(userLatLng);
            mSearchCircle.setRadius(radius);
        }
    }
}
```

The radius is determined with a SeekBar, like so (I removed some unrelated code):

```
@Override
public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
    final int radius = progress + DEFAULT_MIN_RADIUS;
    drawMapSearchRadius(radius);
...
```

When I slide the SeekBar, the radius of the circle changes as expected, but it is visibly flickering a lot. It looks and feels just very bad.

Did anyone experience this error and could tell me what I did wrong or what I could do better to limit or, in the best case, eliminate the circle flickering?

Thanks in advance

EDIT: [Apparently it's a bug existing for over a year already, acknowledged by Google last month.](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=5707&q=type%3DDefect%20apitype%3DAndroid2%20label%3AType-Defect&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Introduced%20Fixed%20Summary%20Stars%20ApiType%20Internal)

Since Google is not known for fixing errors like this quickly, I have very little hope for a fix.. So I guess my question is changing to this: Are there any workarounds for the meantime?

Comment: Did you find a workaround?

Comment: Only a very cumbersome one that does not work with a 3d tilted map. I did it by adding an extra view over the map and scaling and moving it (bypassing the whole map fragment). It works, but I would not recommend it. 
Also check out the link I posted, there are always some nice new tips and workarounds there! Good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This [issue (5707)](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=5707) has been [solved on October 24, 2016](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/releases)

Comment: I haven't tested it yet, but I am trusting the Google Maps team on this. A bug fix 3 years in the making. Thanks for the info.