# Circle animation on google map in android

Tags: android, google-maps, animation

doing circle animation on google map using valu animation but animation gets flickered and blinking all the time.

Here is a code,

```
 CircleOptions circleOptions = new CircleOptions()
                .center(searchStopPoint)   //set center
                .radius(100)   //set radius in meters
                .strokeColor(Color.TRANSPARENT)
                .fillColor(0x555751FF)
                .strokeWidth(5);

    busStopCircle = googleMap.addCircle(circleOptions);
    ValueAnimator valueAnimator = new ValueAnimator();
    valueAnimator.setRepeatCount(ValueAnimator.INFINITE);
    valueAnimator.setRepeatMode(ValueAnimator.RESTART);
    valueAnimator.setIntValues(0, 100);
    valueAnimator.setDuration(3000);
    valueAnimator.setEvaluator(new IntEvaluator());
    valueAnimator.setInterpolator(new AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator());
    valueAnimator.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator valueAnimator) {
            float animatedFraction = valueAnimator.getAnimatedFraction();              
            busStopCircle.setRadius(animatedFraction * 100);
        }
    });

    valueAnimator.start();
```

Can anyone helps me to to make it smooth animation without flickering..

Thanks

Comment: The flicker happens on a real device or in the emulator?

Comment: @Tasos both the device

Comment: i had a look at the docs, and you have INFINITE and then RESTART -- RESTART When the animation reaches the end and repeatCount is INFINITE or a positive value, the animation restarts from the beginning. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/animation/ValueAnimator.html -- any reason why you keep animating the circles??

Comment: i am putting this circle at specific location to make it highlighted and indicating as different than other locations. need to put semi transparent circle with some animation.

Comment: yeah i understand but can you try animating just the once without repeating as a test to see if the blinking flickers go away. that would narrow it down to the animation itself

Comment: also have a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17278015/google-maps-android-api-v2-visualizing-the-search-radius-with-the-helping-of-va -- it may be the (.fillColor(0x555751FF))  that is the issue

Comment: Checkout that link, they given the default color from the Color class and i have given my own color, though i have tried with that  same happening

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101100/discussion-between-jatin-and-tasos).

Comment: @Tasos I can reproduce this with RESTART and REVERSE.

Comment: any solutions / workaround for the same? I am also struggling with the flickering, while animating the Circle object drawn using maps api.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Circle on Google Maps for Android v2 is flickering when size changes by seekbar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26509591/circle-on-google-maps-for-android-v2-is-flickering-when-size-changes-by-seekbar)

Answer (score 5):

This is a [known issue](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=5707). One workaround would be to use a [GroundOverlay](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/GroundOverlay) instead of a circle.
Here's a sample:
Create the circle :

```
// The drawable to use for the circle
    GradientDrawable d = new GradientDrawable();
    d.setShape(GradientDrawable.OVAL);
    d.setSize(500,500);
    d.setColor(0x555751FF);
    d.setStroke(5, Color.TRANSPARENT);

    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(d.getIntrinsicWidth()
            , d.getIntrinsicHeight()
            , Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

    // Convert the drawable to bitmap
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
    d.setBounds(0, 0, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight());
    d.draw(canvas);

    // Radius of the circle
    final int radius = 100;

    // Add the circle to the map
    final GroundOverlay circle = map.addGroundOverlay(new GroundOverlayOptions()
    .position(searchStopPoint, 2 * radius).image(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(bitmap)));
```

Now animate the circular overlay :

```
ValueAnimator valueAnimator = new ValueAnimator();
    valueAnimator.setRepeatCount(ValueAnimator.INFINITE);
    valueAnimator.setRepeatMode(ValueAnimator.RESTART);
    valueAnimator.setIntValues(0, radius);
    valueAnimator.setDuration(3000);
    valueAnimator.setEvaluator(new IntEvaluator());
    valueAnimator.setInterpolator(new AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator());
    valueAnimator.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator valueAnimator) {
            float animatedFraction = valueAnimator.getAnimatedFraction();
            circle.setDimensions(animatedFraction * radius * 2);
        }
    });

    valueAnimator.start();
```

**UPDATE** : This issue [has been fixed](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/releases#october_24_2016)

Comment: I'm using the latest version of play services. But still circle rendering is not that much fast.  Is GroundOverlay still the better option that CircleOptions even when google claims the issue to be fixed?